# Monitor won't turn on when I change BIOS settings

Tags: display, bios

I need to change the BIOS settings on my computer. When I get to the BIOS settings, though, my monitors won't display anything, making it impossible for me to make any changes. (During normal startup, my monitors won't show anything until Windows is booted, either.)

My computer is a [Lenovo H430](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/research/hints-or-tips/detail.page?DocID=HT073549). I have two monitors, an [Asus VE198T](https://www.asus.com/Monitors_Projectors/VE198T/) and a [Crossover 27Q-LED](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BJFMK1W). The Asus is connected by VGA and the Crossover, by DVI.

What can I do to have the monitors turn on when I go to the BIOS settings? Will I need to use a different monitor?

Comment: Which BIOS setting are you wanting to change?

Comment: I want to turn on virtualization support.

Comment: You may need to reset your BIOS to default settings. Do you have a PCI/PCI-E graphics card? you could try removing this and plugging a monitor into the on-board graphics card to see if you can get to your BIOS screen

Comment: Yeah, as @BigChris said, it might have to do with your graphics card. There is often a setting like "init display". See if there is any word on that in the computer manual, under the BIOS settings section.

Comment: @Big Chris That was what I needed to do. Can you please post it as an answer?

Comment: Yeah... you did say that both monitors are connected with VGA cables. I was like "whaat?" Because this computer only has one VGA port on the back. So did you have to remove the graphics card? Or did you just connect the VGA cable to the VGA port on the back?

Comment: @sammyg I was wrong about using two VGA cables. I'm actually using one VGA and one DVI. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Oh, I see... Well, for the future, you should see if you have the option I mentioned in your BIOS settings. Common parameters are PEG (PCI Express Graphics), PCI and Onboard Graphics. I bet your BIOS setting is set to onboard graphics. But if you intend to use a dedicated PCI-Express graphics card (e.g. DVI port), you could change that to PEG, and it should work.

Comment: @Kevin When you say that Asus monitor is connected by VGA, is it connected to the built-in VGA port next to the PS/2 mouse/keyboard ports? Or to another VGA on the PCI Express graphics card you installed? And also, what exactly did you have to do to get to the BIOS screen? Did you in fact have to clear CMOS (reset your BIOS)? I would appreciate if you could just clarify this a little bit.

Comment: We tried unplugging the monitor connected by DVI altogether and just using the VGA monitor. We plugged the VGA monitor both into the on-board video card and the third-party card; neither one worked. To get to the BIOS settings, we had to remove the third-party video card altogether, then put it back in after I changed the settings. I didn't spend too much time seeing if there was a setting we could have changed to get to the BIOS settings more easily in the future. We did not clear CMOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you first turn on your computer, your graphics drivers will not have loaded - so any display you get from your PCI/AGP/PCI-E graphics card will be potentially limited.

To get display instantly at boot time, it is recommended that you plug a monitor into the onboard VGA adapter on your motherboard (and remove the monitor cables from all other graphics ports).  This should force your onboard card online for POST/boot and enable you to complete the BIOS modifications you require.

Looking at Google image search results for "Lenovo H430 ports" - it appears that you have an onboard VGA adapter right next to the keyboard/mouse PS/2 ports which is the one you need to use for this.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to reset your BIOS to default settings. Do you have a PCI/PCI-E graphics card? You could try removing this and plugging a monitor into the on-board graphics card to see if you can get to your BIOS screen.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the BIOS set-up wasn't accessed. I tried literally everything. I fixed it by changing the HDMI cable into a normal VGA one. The BIOS screen immediately showed up.

Just plug-in a VGA cable from your monitor to the PC and it'll fix it :)